# what is the difference between user owner and role owner in ITIM?

Tags: tivoli-identity-manager

In role administration what is the difference between role owner and user owner ?

Also, when we say a role can act as a participant and principal, what does it mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the wording itself indicates,

**Role owner** is a Role that is the owner of the current role

**User owner** is a specific person in ITIM that is the owner of the current role

When it comes to roles acting as participants, you can think about workflows. An example is when you have an approval workflow. Your business rules might say that the for en employee to get a mail account one of the managers needs to approve the request. Let's also assume that you have a Role in ITIM, let's say "Level X Manager" and this has a few members. According to the business rules, if you as an employee request an email account, anyone that has the Level X Manager role can approve the request.

You would model this in an approval workflow, and in the approval node, the Participant entity would be the role "Level X Manager". When you will request the account, ITIM will send notifications to anyone that has the Level X Manager role and any of them can approve the request.

Comment: I think i understand now, that if a role is a owner of itself, the members of the role act as participants in approving the request.. correct ?  
Could you please explain a bit more the use of being a user owner
and also what does it mean when a role act a principle ?

Comment: No, that is not correct. The example with the approval touched upon the role as participant.
 - The role owner is a separate discussion, and it is summarized in the first two bullet points. I think it is pretty clear. 

You would need to formulate your question in a more concrete manner, it is too open ended right now to get meaningful answers.